# How to put an element (inside jQuery dialog) on top of it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery dialog to make a div pop up (a user form to fill up).
I am using the plugin below for validation.

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

My problem now is that my fields are close to the edges of the dialog, and when the error tooltips (ex. "Field is required") pops up, it becomes overflown INSIDE the dialog. what I want is to let it float on top of the dialog.

here is a picture.

[image: Error]

Comment: A live link will definitely help. Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or give a working example

Comment: I personally would always add the tooltip as a direct child of the body (not inside the dialog) and position it absolutely either relative to the element it relates to or the mouse. You may or may not need to set the z-index of the tooltip then, I am not 100% on how z-index works as I think it is different particularly in earlier browsers (IE 6 for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with giving `overflow:visible` the dialog container (the one that has the scrollbar - use your browser's Inspect Element functionality to find which one it is).

Comment: overflow:visible is the closes solution I could get :). Although the tooltip can now get on top of the title bar, but it's not render OUTSIDE the dialog. it is still cut on the edges of the dialog.
Nevertheless, thanks anyway! :)

Comment: You can try adding `overflow:visible` to parent elements until the tooltips aren't clipped by the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Try using an older version of the plugin ex:2.5. In that version the container of the message is appended to the body of the document not the form so the messages are always visible. I don't know why they changed this.

Answer (score 0):

Give a higher z-index to the tooltip.

For example if your dialog box has a z-index: 1000; Give the tooltip z-index:2000;

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work (I guess :D). I checked their indices. I right clicked the dialog title bar and its z-index is 1000 something while my tooltip has around 5k :/

Comment: oops .. that's strange. z-index has always worked for me. Can you somehow share the code?

Comment: I'll make a dummy later sir(the page is too large). will try to update :) Thanks.